# Angular 2 md-radio buttons in reactive (model based) forms don't work & stop md-input display

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, radio-button, angular-material2

I am following instructions for reactive form radio buttons at http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/api/forms/index/radiocontrolvalueaccessor-directive  and using Angular 2.1.2 and Google's MD-alpha.10 Atom-typescript says I have no errors. I get the following console errors.

```
core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/input/postApartment4Rent.component.html:47:62 caused by: No value accessor for form control with name: 'pets'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'pets'
at _throwError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1231:15)
at setUpControl (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1171:13)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:3595:13)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4029:48)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:3975:22)
at Wrapper_FormControlName.detectChangesInInputProps (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormControlName/wrapper.ngfactory.js:44:18)
at _View_PostApartmentComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/PostApartmentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:4994:30)
at _View_PostApartmentComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
at _View_PostApartmentComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
at _View_PostApartmentComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:23)
```

Relevant code is the following:

**HTML** for form component's view

```
<form [formGroup]="registerApartment4RentForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">

<p id="petsPolicy" class="required" aria-labelledby="petsPolicy"
  i18n="select summary pets policy">Pets Policy - Summarized</p>
<md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button i18n="No pets allowed" value="no_pets" formControlName="pets">No pets allowed</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button i18n="Cats allowed" value="cats_allowed" formControlName="pets">Cats allowed</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

**Component** to manage the form

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({ ...etc.})

export class PostApartmentComponent {
  registerApartment4RentForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerApartment4RentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    city: '',
    zipCode: '',
    streetAddress: '',
    pets: ''
    });
   }
  }
  form = new FormGroup({
  pets: new FormControl( )
  });
}
```

I tried importing FormControlName, but it did not help. In addition to the error statement, the radio buttons don't switch as a new button gets clicked and the button circles appear as 2 side by side, instead of 1 inside the other. Also all the md-inputs do not display. When

```
formControlName="pets"
```

is removed from the md-ratio-button HTML, the md-inputs re-appear and work.

I've copied code out of the devdocs for reactive forms and changed variable names. What else has to be done to get md-radio-buttons working?

Comment: I posted this situation in Angular Material2's Issues as #1875. As of 22 November, it is an open issue. It is not clear, to me, whether the issue is code problems or documentation errors.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue until I figured out, that you have to set the `formControlName` on the `md-radio-group` component:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="userInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <md-radio-group name="gender" formControlName="gender">

        <md-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value="Female">
          Female
        </md-radio-button>

        <md-radio-button class="example-radio-button" value="Male">
          Male
        </md-radio-button>  

      </md-radio-group>

</form>
```

Comment: I'm glad it was useful for u @m4design :)